# Giving an error while implementing owl-carousel? Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, django-templates, owl-carousel

I was trying to implement basic carousel in my django ecommerce website for my products. However, I have an error while implementing.I don't know what is the problem. It's giving this error: 'Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function'. Maybe this error is the reason for that it is not working.
Files, that I have imported:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/owl.carousel.min.js' %}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/owl.carousel.min.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/owl.theme.default.min.css' %}">
```

**html**

```
<div class="row owl-carousel" style="width:80%;position: relative; left:10%;">

  {% for product in products %}
                      <div class="store col-lg-3 col-6 item">
                        <div class="single-product">
                          <div class="single-product">
  <div class="header-single-product">
  <p style="margin-top:-10px;margin-bottom:-10px" class="code">Код: 51265</p>
  {% if product in wishedProductsList %}
  <i class="bi bi-heart-fill addWishlist" style="color: red" data-product="{{product.id}}" data-action="add"></i>
  {% else %}
  <i class="bi bi-heart addWishlist"  data-product="{{product.id}}" data-action="add"></i>
  {% endif %}
    <i class="fa fa-balance-scale" style="margin-right:5px;"></i>

  </div>
  <div class="product-image">
    <a href="{% url 'product_details' product.category.slug product.slug %}"><img style="width: 100%;height: 100%;" src="{{product.imageURL}}"></a>
  </div>
  <p style="color:#617375;">В наличии</p>
  <p style="color:black;">{{product.name}}</p>
  <p>.....</p>
  <p>.....</p>
  <p>.....</p>
  <p class="price">Цена: {{product.price}}</p>

  <div class="counter">
    <div class="arrow-up increase" id="arrow-up" data-product="{{product.id}}" data-action="plus" ><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></div>
    <div class="quantity"><input type="number" class="quantity" value="1" data-product="{{product.id}}"></div>
    <div class="arrow-down increase" id="arrow-down" data-product="{{product.id}}" data-action="minus"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></div>
</div>
  <div class="product-foot"><div class="product-action-2">
                                <button data-product="{{product.id}}" style="width:100%;height: 50px;" data-action="add" class="btn btn-outline-secondary add-btn update-cart">В Корзину</button>
                              </div></div>
 
</div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                        <div class="angle angle-right next" style="float:right;"><img src="{% static 'images/angle-right.png' %}"></div>
                      </div>
```

**javascript**

```
<script>
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
})
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Seems like jquery is not included correct.

Comment: Do you know how to include properly? I tried through link as well. But, the problem is not solved

Comment: Where exactly is your `$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({` script in relation to the `js/jquery.min.js` script?   If your script is first, explains it.  If your script is last, there may be another jquery.js or `$.noconflict` called (redefining `$`).  Your page errors show a 404 on colors.js, but colors.js is not in your code, similar with jqmigrate - which appears *after* your $ is not defined error - so looks like your code is just too soon in the document - move your `<script> $(".owl...` tag to the end, just before `</body>`

Comment: Did as you said. I think it worked. But, now another error 'Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function'.

Comment: Add this `<script>console.log($.fn.jquery)</script>` immediately after your `<script src=..jquery.js` and immediately before you get `is not a function` error.  You should have two values, please provide them here.

Comment: the error states that jquery is included correctly but owlcarousel is not. at least its not included when the initialization script runs, so maybe its a problem of order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One time i had seem problem. Answer was in jQuery conflict with $ calls.
So try initialize owl in this way:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
});
});
</script>
```

And be shure that yours `js/jquery.min.js` and `js/owl.carousel.min.js` has right path and dont use any of `defer` or `async` attributes and included in head section.